# \rightsquigarrow with the text above and below it

Tags: text-manipulation, xrightarrow

is it possible to write a text above and below the `\rightsquigarrow`? I am trying `\xrightsquigarrow[\text{b}]{\text{a}}`, but it is not working.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/460248/156344) may help.

Comment: @JouleV, I don't see how it could help. The OP wants arrows not operators.

Comment: @Sigur My answer on that question works for everything, not only operators.

Comment: @JouleV, you don't mention `\overset{}` there. I suppose you suggest `$\underset{b}{\overset{a}{\rightsquigarrow}}$`.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a new command to achieve it using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stackengine}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123219/writing-above-and-below-a-symbol-simultaneously
\newcommand\stackrqarrow[2]{%
    \mathrel{\stackunder[2pt]{\stackon[4pt]{$\rightsquigarrow$}{$\scriptscriptstyle#1$}}{%
            $\scriptscriptstyle#2$}}}
\begin{document}
$   x \stackrqarrow{a}{b} y$
\end{document}
```

to get:

[image]

Comment: thanks. it works. however the lenght of the arrow does not grows according to the lenght of the text above/below, differently of the case of `\xrightarrow{\text{a}}{\text{a}}`.

Comment: @PolianeLima That is a completely different question instead.

Comment: oh, i see. i am sorry. Do you know the answer?

Comment: @PolianeLima If you can post it as a new question, I or someone else can try to answer it. If you prefer `TikZ` way of doing it, then it is definitely possible ;)

Comment: Yes - it has already been answered in TikZ - see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60216/how-to-create-a-squiggle-arrow-with-some-text-on-it-in-tikz